# How to interpret a formula from the handbook of applied cryptography

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness

In the handbook of applied cryptography, we can find the following formula for testing PRNG. My question is what does mean `2` in the upper index of the `n_00` and others? It is not power because then the formula does not make sense.

[image: formula]
([source](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/362884265668771842/420600646849527809/unknown.png))

Comment: $n_{ab}$ should be the number of the sequence `ab` appearing, so squaring over the integer should make sense here?

Comment: As you can see it follow chi square so result shall be bellow 1.0

Comment: Did you mean this "answer" to be a response to my comment or to kodlu's (community wiki) answer?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32008)

Comment: whd, you may want to [merge your two accounts](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 4):

The comment by @SEJPM is correct, all those subscripted $n_0,n_{01}$ etc are nonnegative integers counting the occurrences of subsequences such as $0,01$ respectively.

So no problem with exponentiation and for example $n_{00}^2$ is indeed the square of the number of times the pattern $00$ appears.